# Is there a good alternative for protected Nelson Sauvin Hop?

Tags: hops, growing-hops

I would like to plant Hoop similar to Nelson Sauvin in Switzerland (Europe).
This NZ hop appears to be under licence, so there is no chance to buy rhizome or plants.

Reference : http://www.nzhops.co.nz/variety/nelson-sauvin

Is there a known alternative?
Where would it be possible to buy it?

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to say this but there isn't really a substitute for Nelson Sauvin it is a rather unique hop. Some people suggest: Riwaka, Motueka; but they are not to my mind a reasonable substitute.

I really think you are going to struggle to find anywhere selling NS rhizomes, they don't seem to be available for sale.

Comment: From the later research I've made online, this seems the definitive answer.